# .NET: How to determine programmatically whether a .NET application has been compiled?

Tags: c++, .net, windows, system-administration

I need to install some script/application that runs every time at startup and performs some operations under the user privileges.

My script would check whether the current version of certain .NET application (which runs **very slow** if not compiled, **very fast** if compiled) has been compiled. If negative, it would compile it (with `NGEN.EXE`). As we know the .NET apps must be compiled on a machine-by-machine basis.

This check must be performed every time the machine starts up.

Question: Would you recommend to implement this with C#, C++ or with some script? Can you please provide details?

TIA.

Comment: I think, You're talking about pre-compilation when you reference services in your app. On .Net project property you have checkbox that you can check to pre-compile everything when you build the Dll. It will generate another *.XmlSerializers.dll, which you then can distribute together with your other Dll

Comment: The closest I found (MSVS-2010) under `Properties` is a check mark `Build | Optimize Code`

Comment: I honestly don't know on c++ project but in VS 2012 in c# project properties this is on Build screen - dropdown "Generate Serialization Assembly". Options - Auto, On, Off.

Comment: The DLL is built by Microsoft. It is `OpenXML SDK`. My app uses it.

Comment: This is a  C# application.

Comment: If this is not Dll that you generate then, I guess, you do need to run `ngen` to speed up first calls. Why can't you run it once and then just distribute it? I mean, distribute generated Dll?

Comment: Because `NGEN` does not perform a real compilation of the executable. What it does is to compile the required .NET libraries that live under the .NET area. Therefore, I need to repeat the NGEN for every computer.

Comment: NGEN saves a checksum of the *.EXE file. Every time I deploy a new version of the app, the checksum varies and therefore have to run NGEN again, in every computer where my app will run.

Comment: Okay, I found `Generate Serialization Assembly` (in VS-2010 and 2012). I guess it is worth a try.

Comment: Also, check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163610.aspx

Comment: "Unlike statically compiled binaries, NGen images are tied to the machine where they are created and hence cannot be deployed." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163610.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esteemed Self:

All you need to do is determine the date of `MyApp.exe` and compare it with the date of

```
C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages*\*\MyApp.ni.exe
```

If the latter is older, you need to recompile.

You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any point in trying to find out, ngen.exe already can do this by itself.  Just run:

> ngen.exe update /queue

The update command tells it to look for native images that are no longer valid.  The /queue option tells it to perform the job in the background.

Targeting a specific assembly is done with

> ngen.exe *assemblypath* install /queue

Comment: This solution is too good to be true. Am trying it as we speak. It takes a **LOT** of time, and I am interested in only one application.

Comment: It is only normal when assemblies didn't get uninstalled properly.  Are you messing with the GAC a lot?  Time for a cleanup perhaps.  Second time you run it surely ought to look better.

Comment: "Are you messing with the GAC a lot?" First time. I am a total .NET newbie.

Comment: In the 1st. run, it took almost 30 minutes. I am running it again.

Comment: In the 2nd. run, it took 15 minutes. The bad news is that after `NGEN UPDATE` the application did NOT run any faster. Had to compile it individually (with `NGEN INSTALL`)

Comment: No idea what might be wrong, you'd better stick with install then.

Comment: I guess all I need to find out is how to determine whether the app is already compiled, because running `NGEN INSTALL myApp` is trivially easy, under a script or under C++/C#.

Comment: That is still not necessary, note how you get the "All targets are up to date" message when you run it again.

Comment: Hans: I am a total newbie, but hear me out. I am under the impression that `NGEN UPDATE` compiles the assembly that is slowing my app down, but it has no way (unless it checks my whole hard disk, including network-mounted volumes) to determine that my app "MYAPP.EXE" exists. All `NGEN INSTALL` does is to take a checksum of `MYAPP.EXE` with a note: "We can make this baby run a lot faster!" This last part is the missing link, which explains why I had to run `NGEN INSTALL` earlier. Then again, .NET is a mysterious creature.

Comment: In short: MYAPP.EXE is not necessarily one of "All targets are up to date". Every time a .NET app attempts to start, the checksum of the app is computed and a lookup is done, to see whether that target is in the database of targets.